# Debug in visual studio using contents of files as command line arguments

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, command-line-arguments

I am using visual studio to develop a command line program which takes certain parameters from the command line arguments and its input from the stdin. Currently I am debugging it by setting the parameters manually in project properties as seen in the screenshot:

[image]

However I am using a script to generate and compare input, parameters and outputs and I would like to debug the errors, once I have found the appropriate inputs/params/outputs with my script, inside visual studio. Currently I have to manually copy the parameters, I would like to have them read from `param.txt` which is in the same directory as `input.txt` which works as an input.

Comment: Not sure this is possible: suppose you'd use `cat params.txt | $(TargetPath)` the VS would start debugging cat.exe, not your executable. A nicer solution would be to use a decent argument parsing api which allows reading arguments from a file.

Comment: @stijn isn´t it possible to escape the command in some way? Such as you would use $(cat params.txt) in a script

Comment: I assume not, as I'm guessing (not sure though) that VS starts the Command directly and not in a cmd.exe host so there's no script envronment available. You could als put a DebugBreak() statement in main and then run cat params.txt | $(TargetPath) or so manually and attach the debugger.